# Using custom generator with zip to train a model in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generator, yield

I wanted to use a custom generator function to train the model. I am returning 3 different outputs using yield and storing them in separate variables using zip function. I don't if it is directly possible to use the yield values without storing in separate variables, since 2 variables are used as input in model.fit() and remaining 1 is output. **Whenever I call the generator function to store the yield iterator it causes memory overload** and restart the kernel.
I have attached my kaggle link as well as the generator code below.
[Kaggle notebook link](https://www.kaggle.com/ankitkumaryadav/imagecaptioning-using-cnn-and-lstm-working)

```
def generator(photo, caption):
#     n_samples = 0
    
#     X = []
#     y_in = []
#     y_out = []
    
    for k, vv in caption.items():    #loop over caption dict k is image key(name) vv is caption list for that image
        for v in vv:                #loop over each caption of the caption list for encoding
            for i in range(1, len(v)): #encoding each word  of the current caption

                in_seq= [v[:i]]   #taking encoded part before current word 
                out_seq = v[i]    #the current word

                in_seq = pad_sequences(in_seq, maxlen=MAX_LEN, padding='post', truncating='post')[0]    #padding upto the total chars in whole caption
                out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=VOCAB_SIZE)[0]   #padding 
                yield [photo[k],in_seq],out_seq  #passing the values for training the model


#Whenever I run this line the kernel dies because of less memory
X, y_in, y_out = zip(*generator(images_features, captions_dict))   # THIS IS THE ONE CAUSING ISSUES
  

model.fit([X, y_in], y_out, batch_size=50, epochs=50)    #training the model
```

Comment: Could you add comments in your code to explain what it is doing ? What have you tried to debug ?

Comment: In your code, could you give example data of `images_features` and `captions_dict` ? Ideally could you give us a [example]?